# Retrieve User Info Via Username From sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been working on a website where I am storing user data like, userid, username, password, email, rank, fname, and lname. I have created a registration page that inserts this data and a login page that requires your username and password. This creates a session and in the session with a username variable. How do I use the username to pull from the sql to find, for example, their email? I have tried looking this up but have found nothing. If someone would not mind linking me to a tutorial or something that would be amazing.

Thank you very much,
John Finberg

Comment: Better you refer http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

First search wether username is exists in the database table or not with below query.
**select count(*) from Employee where UserName=@username**. 
if username is already available in the table then get the EmailId by using below query.
**select UserName, EmailId from Employee where UserName=@username**

Comment: So I have this code to check if the username is there: $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_po` WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."' ")or die(mysql_error());
                                $arr = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                                $num = mysql_numrows($query); //this will count the rows (if exists)

Comment: Yes.
just check if $num is >0 then get mailId using UserName as like below.
 $query= mysql_query("SELECT username,EmailId FROM users_po WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' ")

Comment: Okay. Then how would I go about echoing the email out?

Comment: The given query will return the table with two columns username and emailId, so from that table you can fetch the emailId of corresponding username.

Comment: When I echo it I get, "Resource id #7."

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure that will take the username as parameter and return user's email address:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetUserRole] @userName VARCHAR(255)
               ,@emailaddress NVARCHAR(255) = '' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @emailaddress = u.emailaddress
        FROM [User] u 
        WHERE u.UserName = @userName 
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        THROW
    END CATCH
END
```

You can then call this stored procedure to get the email address for the username that you pass:

```
DECLARE @emailaddress NVARCHAR(255)
[dbo].[uspGetUserRole] 'domain\username1', @emailaddress OUTPUT
SELECT @emailaddress
```

Comment: I also need to be able to get items like rank and pull them up similar to this, $_SESSION['rank'].

Comment: What about for getting a rank or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

1.User can't login with there user name because username is may be a same but use of user id or user email that must be a unique.

2.on login retrieve a user data by user id or email stored there user name and user id in session.

3.now you can retrieve a user data by user id.

Comment: But what would be the code to retrieve the user data?